# Multithreaded WebRequests being executed in succession

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am building a web scraper in C# that deals with proxies and a large volume of requests. The pages are loaded through a ConnectionManager class that grabs a proxy and retries loading that page with random proxies until the page is correctly loaded.

On average, a single task will take somewhere between 100 and 300 requests, and to speed up the process, I have designed the method to use multithreading to simultaneously download the webpages.

```
        public Review[] getReviewsMultithreaded(int reviewCount)
    {
        ArrayList reviewList = new ArrayList();
        int currentIndex = 0;
        int currentPage = 1;
        int totalPages = (reviewCount / 10) + 1;
        bool threadHasMoreWork = true;
        Object pageLock = new Object();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[Program.maxScraperThreads];

        for(int i = 0; i < Program.maxScraperThreads; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = (new Thread(() => 
            {
                while (threadHasMoreWork)
                {
                    HtmlDocument doc;
                    lock(pageLock)
                    {
                        if (currentPage <= totalPages)
                        {
                            string builtString = "http://www.example.com/reviews/" + _ID + "?pageNumber=" + currentPage;
                            //Log.WriteLine(builtString);
                            currentPage++;
                            doc = Program.conManager.loadDocument(builtString);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            threadHasMoreWork = false;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    try
                        {
                            //Get info from page and add to list
                            reviewList.Add(cRev);
                        }
                        Log.WriteLine(_asin + " reviews scraped: " + reviewList.Count);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { continue; }
                }
            }));
            threads[i].Start();
        }

        bool threadsAreRunning = true;
        while(threadsAreRunning) //this is in a separate thread itself, so as not to interrupt the GUI
        {
            threadsAreRunning = false;
            foreach (Thread t in threads)
                if (t.IsAlive)
                {
                    threadsAreRunning = true;
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
        }

        //flatten the arraylist to a primitive
        return reviewArray;
    }
```

However, I have noticed that the requests are still largely being handled one at a time, and as a result the method isn't much faster than it was before. Is the lock causing problems? Is the fact that the ConnectionManager is instantiated in one object and each thread is calling the loadDocument from the same object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, nevermind. I noticed the lock included the call to the method that loads the pages, and because of that only one page was loading at a time.